# Passing Session variable from one controller to another

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a session for User Login as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserLogin lc)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("UserLogin");
    sqlconn.Open();
    sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", lc.Email);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", lc.Password);
    SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
    
    if(sdr.Read())
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(lc.Email, true);
        Session["Email"] = lc.Email.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
    }
```

Now I need to use the Session variable stored here in another controller. How can I do so?

Comment: Have you tried `var email = Session["Email"]`;?

Comment: This looks a lot like you're storing plain-text passwords in the DB, which is very much not okay. It's one of those things you shouldn't even do for practice/learning/proof of concept projects.

Answer (score 0):

Session Variable works with HTTP Request you'll get the session variable in any controller inherited from BaseController after once you have set the Session variable key value.As Session is a Dictionary Type Object.